# Downside to storing objects in jsp application scope

Tags: jsp

I am working on an application mainly jsp/jstl. I am thinking of storing the lookup tables data in the application scope. Is there any downside to this approach ? I am thinking they are fairly static, it should be ok. Is there a better design approach ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There won't be any performance issues with this. Frequently used lookup data can be kept in application scope which will improve the performance. We do that in our web sites.

Comment: Thanks Ravi, I am guessing, I have to write a seperate servlet to do the initial loading.

Comment: What if we are talking about load balancing between multiple servers.  Would the application scope data be replicated?

Comment: No idea about load balancing situation.